# How to count french characters?

Tags: python

I have a function that is splitting all words and checking whether it exceeds 245 characters or no. What I want to do is to check if there are any french characters (char) and count them as 2. For instance letter 'a' is counted as 1 but 'à' should be counted as 2.

```
def count_chars(content: str) -> str:
    chars = ['à', 'â', 'æ', 'ç', 'é', 'è', 'ê', 'ë', 'î', 'ï', 'ô', 'œ', 'ù', 'û', 'ü', 'ÿ',
             'À', 'Â', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'É', 'È', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ô', 'Œ', 'Ù', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ÿ']
    words = content.split()
    new_content = ''
    for word in words:
        if len(new_content + word) <= 245:
            new_content += ' ' + word
        else:
            break
    return new_content.strip()
```

Comment: One way would be to test if the char is (not) in `string.ascii_letters`.

Comment: Your current code is checking each word, rather than each character. I'm unclear on what your intended output is here. Could you give some sample input/output to clarify?

Comment: sorry for being inaccurate. What I meant is that my function is splitting words and checking if the total number of charaters is 245. I will modify my question shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to keep a length variable:

```py
def count_chars(content: str) -> str:
    chars = {'à', 'â', 'æ', 'ç', 'é', 'è', 'ê', 'ë', 'î', 'ï', 'ô', 'œ', 'ù', 'û', 'ü', 'ÿ',
             'À', 'Â', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'É', 'È', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ô', 'Œ', 'Ù', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ÿ'}
    words = content.split()
    new_content = ''
    length = 0
    for word in words:
        word_length = sum(2 if i in chars else 1 for char in word)
        if length + word_length <= 245:
            new_content += ' ' + word
            length += word_length
        else:
            break
    return new_content.strip()
```

Note: I also turned `chars` into a `set` for a (theoretical) speed of `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

After throughout analysis and research I found much better way to do it. The function below is caculating bytes based on unicode standards so no need to provide with list of characters, link to documentation where everything is exaplained is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html):

```
def utf8len(s):
    return len(s.encode('utf-8'))


def trunc_string(content: str) -> str:
    # split words to count number of characters
    words = content.split()
    new_content = ''
    length = 0
    for word in words:
        # count all non-standard characters as more than 1
        word_length = utf8len(word)
        # check if number of characters is higher than 245
        if length + word_length <= 245:
            new_content += ' ' + word
            length += word_length
        else:
            break
    return new_content.strip()
```